# excel:how to select values from column A which its values don't exist in column B

Tags: excel

```
+-------+--------+
|   A   |   B    |
+-------+--------+
| apple | mouse  |
| pie   | dog    |
| car   | phone  |
| mouse | plane  |
| cat   | bag    |
| dog   | tree   |
| phone | flower |
+-------+--------+
```

table is like this and how to select the values from column A which its values don't exist in column B,then get:

```
+-------+
|   C   |
+-------+
| apple |
| pie   |
| car   |
| cat   |
+-------+
```

I could only use excel in my computer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C1`, write `=if(isna(match(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"")`

[image]